# enable main page scroll when angular material dialog open

Tags: angular, scroll, dialog, angular-material2

I have a requirement where I will have my material dialog and when I am opening it I will not have a vertical scrollbar on dialog, instead I will just use the main page (on which page dialog is opened) scroll, For now what happening is, its blocking any scroll movement on the main page.

[check the stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynebby?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-content-example.html)

so if you see in above stackblitz dialog has lot of content which is not visible because I am not able to scroll down using main page scroll. Its blocking the main page scroll and note I don't want the scroll inside the dialog itself. that is not my requirement unfortunately

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or something else?

Comment: added in the question, Thanks @Farhad

Answer (score 2):

You should add a scroll strategy as an option when the dialog opens. I changed your `openDialog()` function as follows, to include a scroll strategy.

```
export class DialogContentExample {
  constructor( public dialog: MatDialog, private overlay: Overlay ) {}

  openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogContentExampleDialog, {
      scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.noop()
    }); //Added the strategy, after first constructing the variable containing it

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
    });
  }
}
```

You also need to import the library: `import { Overlay } from "@angular/cdk/overlay";`

Here is your refactored [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynebby-rdpntt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-content-example.ts).